# Nginx on docker - daemonize and attach to bash

Tags: bash, nginx, docker

I want to host nginx on a docker container. I've realized that in order to stop the container from exiting instantly i have to configure nginx to 'daemon off'.

However, now I've done this it seems I can't attach to the container to run bash commands. How can I attach to my running nginx container (primarily for learning and making changes whilst in development).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `docker exec my-container-name bash` command (available since docker 1.3). https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec